# How to become an expert in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

Yes, indeed. To anybody who's sole goal is to become an expert in WPF (or you already are) what would you recommend doing to achieve this goal?

- What books would you recommend going through?
- What topics to cover in detail?
- What achievements to make to become an expert?
- Would you recommend to become an expert in other areas as well (.net BCL, Silverlight, Direct 2D)?
- Should this person develop communication skills as well?
- Do you think that such a person like "WPF expert" can even exist?

Thank you!

Comment: very subjective question, though you do have some solid questions.

Comment: at *least* make this a community wiki.

Comment: i don't know if it should be anyones sole goal to be an expert in wpf.  You're sole goal should be "expert application developer", or something a little more general.  WPF alone isn't going to get you anywhere.  Like almost everything, i think the real answer is "practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop many applications using WPF.

It's such a huge platform, I feel that you only learn by forcing yourself to use the platform, in as many ways, for as many different types of applications, as possible.